# Como usar corretamente "quem sabe" e "quem sabe se" para exprimir possibilidade?

Tags: expressões, concordância-verbal, modo-subjuntivo

Para exprimir possibilidade (não conhecimento), há diferença entre as frases

> Quem sabe ...

e

> Quem sabe **se** ...

em termos de significado? De gramática? Quando é que devia usar ou não a conjunção "se"?

Quer dizer, deixando para outras perguntas a escolha entre o presente e o futuro, para exprimir

> Não é certo se ele vai sair.

quais das seguintes frases estão correctas? Porquê?

> 1. Quem sabe ele sai?
> 2. Quem sabe ele saia?
> 3. Quem sabe ele sairia?
> 4. Quem sabe se ele sai?
> 5. Quem sabe se ele saia?
> 6. Quem sabe se ele sairia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Várias das frases são aceitáveis. A frase seguinte está indubitavelmente correta:

> (a) Quem sabe se ele sai?!

Temos duas orações: "quem sabe" é a oração principal; "se ele sai" é uma [oração subordinada substantiva objetiva direta](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint32.php), porque desempenha o papel de objeto direto de "sabe". As orações subordinadas substantivas tem que ser introduzidas por uma conjunção. Prefiro pontuar a frase com "?!" ou até mesmo só com ponto de exclamação ou até ponto final, porque só com ponto de interrogação, dá ideia
que, em vez de exprimires simplesmente dúvida sobre se ele sai ou não, estás a perguntar algo como: "quais entre vocês sabem se ele sai?"

A frase seguinte, que não é equivalente à anterior, também está correta:

> (b) Quem sabe se ele sairia se nós o convidássemos!?

"Sairia" é condicional: neste caso é usado para exprimir uma coisa que aconteceria se se verificasse uma condição (se nós o convidássemos). Se essa condição estiver subentendida, não me choca dizer-se simplesmente, "quem sabe se ele sairia?" Mas não é equivalente a "quem sabe se ele sai?". O condicional também poderia ser empregue para perguntar em relação ao passado. Não consigo encontrar um exemplo convincente com o verbo sair, mas consigo com o verbo estar:

> (c) Quem sabe se ele estaria em casa ontem?!

"Quem sabe se ele saia" não é gramatical.

Agora, as frases sem a conjunção *se*. Coloquialmente é aceitável omitir o "se", mas eu colocaria uma vírgula, que corresponde a uma pausa na fala:

> (d) Quem sabe, ele sai?!

A vírgula, e a correspondente pausa na fala, serve entre outras coisas para indicar a omissão de uma palavra. Agora, encontrei vários exemplos em autores brasileiros de frases do tipo da (d) sem vírgula:

> (e) Ela esperava pela voz do primo. Quem sabe ele também ia dizer alguma coisa ([Cecília Meireles](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cec%C3%ADlia_Meireles), *Olhinhos de Gato*, 1939.)

Para mim, o mais curioso foi encontrar [este site brasileiro](http://portugues.uol.com.br/gramatica/o-modo-subjuntivo.html) dizendo que "quem sabe" deve vir seguido do subjuntivo e não do indicativo, o que tornaria errada a frase do exemplo anterior. Nos exemplos deles, *quem sabe* é usado como *talvez* (que pede o subjuntivo) e não como uma construção do tipo (d), que é do tipo de (a) em que se omitiu o *se*:

> (f) Quem sabe eu ainda seja uma garotinha.

O argumento deles, que *quem sabe* exprime dúvida e por isso exige o subjuntivo, está errado: há maneiras de exprimir dúvida com o indicativo, como nos exemplos (a), (b) e (c), onde o subjuntivo estaria errado, ou como no exemplo do [Aulete digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/sabe), "sabe Deus onde foi parar o rapaz!". De qualquer modo, a posição deles legitima o teu "quem sabe ele saia." Portanto a única que está de todo errada é a tua (5), "quem sabe se ele saia."

Comment: Encontrei a forma #2 duas vezes num livro de criança. Sem vírgula, com subjuntivo. A editora é do Brasil, talvez é uma diferença transatlântica?

Comment: O "saia" pode ser um falar popular, mas não é norma culta. Agora, sem "se" e sem vírgula está errado, no Brasil e em qualquer lado. Podes dizer, "quem sabe isso" ou "quem conhece ele" sem vírgula nem pausa depois do "sabe". Mas quando dizes, "quem sabe ele saia" tens que fazer uma pausa depois do sabe. Na escrita isso representa-se por uma vírgula.

Comment: @DanGetz: O link na minha resposta é de um site brasileiro. A forma #4 segue exatamente o formato dos exemplos que lá encontras (a maioria dos exemplos são com "que", mas também há com "se"). [Duas páginas antes tens outro exemplo](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint30.php)

Comment: As suas explicações conforme quase exactamente aos meus preconceitos como falador do inglês; daqui o meu ceticismo :) Obrigado.

Comment: lol, por outro lado, encontrei num corpus alguns exemplos de "quem sabe ele/ela" + indicativo, sem vírgula e sem se; com subjuntivo não encontrei no corpus, mas encontra-se no google search. Vou qualificar a minha resposta

Comment: @DanGetz: Sim, na verdade há diferenças transantlânticas. Estive a editar a resposta para as refletir.